# JS - construct an event

Tags: javascript

I'm reading this code [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FAPI%2FDOM%2FEvents%2FCreating_and_triggering_events) and I'm wondering what the last line means:

```
function simulateClick() {
 var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
'view': window,
'bubbles': true,
'cancelable': true
 });

 var cb = document.getElementById('checkbox'); 
 var canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: [MDN: EventTarget.dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means `canceled` will be assigned `false` if `cb.dispatchEvent(event)` returns anything **truthy** (i.e. anything but `false`, `0`, `''`, `null`, `undefined` OR `NaN`) and vice-versa.